# display charts,bars,graphs in ipad

Tags: ipad, reporting-services, graph, charts, report

I want the graphs,charts,bars and data to be displayed in my "ipad" from a report that is retrieved from SSRS(I have URL link for the report). Is it possible to write the code and display?

Comment: I had to look up what SSRS was, [but turns out there's a Wikipedia entry for that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Reporting_Services).  AnnaSmith, have you looked into the [open source CorePlot framework](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/) yet?  There are lots of examples Google-able showing how to incorporate it.

Comment: What is this CorePlot Framework? 

Actually I'm working on ipad application in which i have to render ssrs reports on ipad . Please help me.